# Can't get to bring a MKPolylineView to front

Tags: ios, mkpolyline

I have a MKMapView with some routes that sometimes overlaps between them and want to bring a particular one in front of the view. I'm trying this, but doesn't seem to work:

```
[[polylineViewZoom superview] bringSubviewToFront:polylineViewZoom];

polylineViewZoom is a MKPolylineView.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of  accessing `MKPolylineView`'s `superview` directly, use the `insertOverlay:atIndex:` method provided by the `MKMapView` class.

The `insertOverlay:atIndex:` method repositions an overlay that has ***already*** been added to the map (using `addOverlay` or `addOverlays`) in the view/display hierarchy.  By "reposition", I don't mean that the overlay's coordinates change -- just it's z-index controlling its overlap with other overlays.

You pass the `id<MKOverlay>` object to this method (***not*** the `MKOverlayView` or `MKOverlayRenderer`).  The map view internally takes care of manipulating views or layers as needed.

This method will work in both iOS 6 and iOS 7.

For the `index` parameter, a value of 0 means the "bottom" of the view hierarchy and the overlay at the highest `index` will be at the "top" or "in front".

So if you have 5 overlays added to the map, the `index` range is from 0 to 4 and setting an overlay's `index` to 4 will bring it to the front.

Example:

```
//Somewhere earlier, you add the overlay to the map view using
//addOverlay or addOverlays.

//...

//Later, when you want to bring an overlay to the front, get a reference 
//to the overlay either from the map view's overlays array
//or you might keep a reference to it in an instance variable.
id<MKOverlay> someOverlay = ...;

//calculate index for the last ("top") overlay...
NSUInteger maxIndex = self.mapView.overlays.count - 1;

[self.mapView insertOverlay:someOverlay atIndex:maxIndex];
```

Note there are a few other methods related to changing the overlay hierarchy that you may find useful instead (eg. `exchangeOverlay:withOverlay:`, `insertOverlay:aboveOverlay:`, etc).  See the `MKMapView` class reference for details.

Answer (score 0):

If iOS7 you can do it like this

```
[mapView addOverlay:polyline level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads];
```

Then if you wish to bring a polyline to front just remove it from the overlays array and re-add it like

```
[mapView addOverlay:polyline level:MKOverlayLevelAboveLabels];
```

Comment: Thanks Panayot, I'm trying to avoid the remove / re-add solution, so that's why I was trying to use the bringSubviewToFront selector.